# Login and get homepage content with a Bash script

Tags: 7

In some developments for drupal 7, I need connect with one user via a bash script then get the content of the connected homepage.

After several searches, my last try :

```
URL="https://www.mainsite.com/subsiteone/"

curl -s -f -o $output -H "Content-Type:application/xml" --insecure  $URL  -w "@formatsender.conf"  > ./test.txt

formid=$( grep 'input type="hidden" name="form_build_id"' $output | cut -d"=" -f4 | sed -e 's/"//g' | sed -e 's/\/>//g' )
echo $formid #show the good pofm id

curl --request POST ${URL} --data "name=usernameone%26pass=userpasswordone%26form_build_id=$formid%26form_id=user_login"
```

the last curl shows the content of the login page (not connected) without any error message. 
I don't understand where is my mistake..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to double checking your encoding or the headers that you're sending over that might cause the problem. I've found trying to do this with a pure Bash solution very fickle at times. Here's an example function I've used that will login into a D7 site on the **/user** page (an easier manner since every D7 install can be logged in from that path).

```
#!/bin/sh

# https://gist.github.com/cdown/1163649
#Usage: urlencode "string"
function urlencode() {
  old_lc_collate=$LC_COLLATE
  LC_COLLATE=C

  local length="${#1}"
  for (( i = 0; i < length; i++ )); do
    local c="${1:i:1}"
    case $c in
      [a-zA-Z0-9.~_-]) printf "$c" ;;
      *) printf '%%%02X' "'$c" ;;
    esac
  done

  LC_COLLATE=$old_lc_collate
}

#Usage: login "user" "pass"
function login() {
  URL=https://www.example.com/user
  name=$(urlencode "$1")
  pass=$(urlencode "$2")
  post_data="name=$name&pass=$pass"

  #Retrieve login page, login form, & input fields.
  login_page=$(curl -s -H "Content-Type:application/xml"  "$URL")
  login_form=$(echo $login_page | grep -o '<form[^>]*action="/user"[^>]*id="user-login"[^>]*>.*</form>')
  login_input=$(echo $login_form | grep -o '<input[^>]*/>')

  #Create Post Body
  while read -r input; do
    input_field=$(echo "$input" | sed -e 's/.*name="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/')
    if [[ $input_field != "name" && $input_field != "pass" ]]; then
      input_value=$(echo "$input" | sed -e 's/.*value="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/')
      input_field=$(urlencode "$input_field")
      input_value=$(urlencode "$input_value")
      post_data="$post_data&$input_field=$input_value"
    fi
  done <<< "$login_input"

  # Depending on your hosting environment you might need additional headers to make yourself not look like a bot
  user_agent="User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 "
  referer="Referer:https://www.example.com/user"
  origin="Origin:https://www.example.com"
  content_type="Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

  # For further authenticated requests, you will need to parse output "Set-Cookie: ..." and set
  # the session cookie in a -H "Cookie: ..." option
  curl -s -L -H "$content_type" -H "$user_agent" -H "$referer" -H "$origin" --request POST "${URL}?destination=/" --data "$post_data"
}

login 'USER' 'PASS'
```

I've found logging into Drupal via Bash much easier with if you can work with a scripting language that has built in HTTP clients & parsers. Depending on your scenario, you might want to consider that if you need a more robust solution.

Comment: thanks you ! I tested this script and I replace the 'USER' 'PASS' and 'URL' variables. But the curl returns nothing :/

Comment: I print the curl command before his execution. I didn't notice any problem ... I have :   curl -s -L -H Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded -H User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0  -H Referer:https://www.mainsite.com/subsiteone/user -H Origin:https://www.mainsite.com/subsiteone --request POST https://www.mainsite.com/subsiteone?destination=/ --data "name=usernameone&pass=userpasswordone&="

Comment: When I remove the '-H Refere:..." parameter, curl return a page ! but this is (again..) the login page not connected

Comment: I don't want to turn this is to a long debug convo so I'll mention 2 things. 1: Adjust the curl options (e.g. `-v` `-s`) to ensure the request is being made. 2: Make sure that a new session is created; check the `sessions` table or set the `-v` flag to check for the `Set-Cookie:` header; you can parse out the session key and added it to subsequent curl requests (e.g. `-H 'Cookie: SSESS<HASH> = <SESSION>;`) to request any page as an authenticated user.

Answer (score 0):

When you post the user credentials to Drupal, I am pretty sure you need to POST it to `/user/login` and not to the front page.

Then after loggin in, Drupal's default behavior is to redirect the user to `/user`, not the front page. You might succeed appending `?destination=<front>` to the request path, use Rules to redirect the user after login, or use [Login Destination](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_destination) to make sure the site will present you the front page.

You might want to try something like this for your last line:

```
curl --request POST ${URL}/user/login?destination=<front> --data "name=usernameone%26pass=userpasswordone%26form_id=user_login"
```

I believe `form_build_id` is not mandatory, but I am not really sure so you might have to add that. I omitted it in the example.

Comment: This is correct: Maybe the front page contains the login block, but the correct page to submit the login form is not that. Also, I assume Drupal needs to know which submission button has been pressed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I tested with "curl --request POST ${URL}/user/login?destination=<front> --data "name=usernameone%26pass=userpasswordone%26form_id=user_login"" or with the form_build_id but the lhis curl always return me the login page without any error message :/

Comment: It might be due to that ${URL} ends with a slash (/) as well, so the url becomes `https://www.mainsite.com/subsiteone//user/login?destination=<front>`. Try removing one slash. Also check if `https://www.mainsite.com/subsiteone/user/login` in fact shows the login page. Finally, perhaps the ampersands in the query string don't have to be URL-encoded and you can use `name=usernameone&pass=userpasswordone&form_id=user_login`. But these are just guesses.